# Cannot convert float* [] to float**

Tags: c, arrays

I have a function that takes 1d and 2d arrays. 2d array has a length but it depends on the user's input.

```
int eval(char expression[],float* array[]);
```

I am calling this function in another function `myfunction()` like:

```
eval(array1,array2);
```

array1 is declared as global(at the beginning of the code, before all the function declerations and it has constant length). array 2 is declared in `myfunction()` as:

```
float array2[m][n];  //m and n are given in the input
```

I take an error like:

> [Error] cannot convert 'float (*)[(part + 3)]' to 'float**' for
>   argument '2' to 'int eval(char*, float**)

How can i fix this problem? I am trying to declare array2 in global but it also gives error that array length isn't a constant.

Sorry if i am wrong in terms of the context,i am a new member.

Comment: An array of arrays (e.g. `float array2[m][n]`) is not the same as an array of pointers (e.g. `float* array[]`).

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry i already call it like that, i wrote it wrong in the question, i edit it now

Comment: @Kevin I thought they were similar, is this the problem?

Comment: Change the prototype to `int eval(char expression[],int n, float (*array)[n]);` and call it `eval(array1, n, array2);`.

Comment: They are similar in usage (syntax-wise) but are quite different in structure. I'm trying to find a suitable duplicate question.

Comment: @mch now it says array does not declared in this scope

Comment: @NoWay show some code: http://ideone.com/6QA5nr works.